# How to get run Doctrine 2.2, I don't find autoload php file

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, wampserver

I'm on the latest 32 bit WampServer 2 server with php 5.4

I follow the step to download Doctrine 2.2 from Git without problem.
Now I'm at configuration step.

I'm stuck to the first step .
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/configuration.html

Where is the file autoload.php. I have basicaly this folder architecture.

doctrine
..bin 
..lib 
....Doctrine 
......ORM 
......vendor 
........doctrine-build-common
........doctrine-common 
........doctrine-dbal 
........Symfony 
..tests
..tools

there is no autoload.php file in the vendor folder ?. 
where is that file ?. 
Do anybody have a tutorial on how to install Doctrine 2.2 . I already installed Doctrine 1.2 before without problem, but the Doctrine 2.2 is completely different then the old one.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

It uses namespacing for loading classes.